# What use cases warrant multiple business units?

Tags: marketing-cloud, bestpractice

Is there a litmus test for when multiple business units become the best practice for a Marketing Cloud implementation? In the official documentation, I've seen the primary benefits discussing user roles and access to content.

But suppose there is a single execution team in a company with multiple regions (with distinct regulatory concerns), multiple brands (with distinct branding and regulatory concerns), and multiple subscription lists that occasionally overlap.

Would this be a case for multiple business units to manage each region and/or brand?

Or would these be managed better with dynamic content in the sends themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple Business Units will depend on many factors and variants that only can answer.

All Business Units in an Enterprise Account share the same All Subscriber Table. We use multiple BU's because we actually have different Business requirements for example if your teams or products touch a different business model where you want to keep set up different.

For example If your brands are completely different from each other, require different set up and/or components such as sender profiles, you want different IP's to be used, different From/To's, etc. then it would make since

We even separated out Internal Communcations which only deals with Intra company communications. Different lists, different templates, campaigns, etc

But that is the idea that you can keep things separate but can still access the same All Subscriber Data when needed.

We also have a BU unit that we use for testing and development, this is where we build new templates, ideas, that may need some data that comes from the All Subscribers table.